# Android Beep or Light without a Notification object?

Tags: android, notifications

Is there any way to start a beep (yes, a beep sound) or turn on the light of a device without a Notification instance?

With a notification it's easy as shown here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

This is possible to do with iPhone API, and I need the exaclty same behavior on android.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want a beep or a light notification without put a notification in the notification bar ;-)

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but as a workaround, you could create a notification and remove it directly...

Comment: that's exatcly where I'm right now...this is the best approach I figured out....but well...is a workaround :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think thats possible. You will have to stick with the notify and cancel workaround. Just as an example see the TweetDeck android app. In the column settings, there are options on top that say : Notify, Light, Sound, Vibrate.
You can select either of Light, Sound and Vibrate or a combination of these, however, they all need the notify to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the media player and play an audio file.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 2):

for a beep, you can either use:

1. ToneGenerator- generates frequencies and DTMF-like tones for a chosen interval
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html
2. RingtoneManager - allows you to obtain and play the default ringtone for notifications (without using a notification).
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html