# How to play a short beep to Android Phone's loudspeaker programmatically

Tags: android

In order to receive the only short beep sound on loudspeaker I want to send single bit to the loudspeaker directly. Similarly to the LED blink. Is there any possibility to do short beep without any kind of Media Players?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play ringtone/alarm sound in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154940/how-to-make-a-beep-in-android

Comment: Yes, the best way is to use NDK. Thanks!

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I recommend you use the [`ToneGenerator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator) class. It requires no audio files, no media player, and you can customize the beep's volume, duration (in milliseconds) and Tone type. I like this one:

```
ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);             
toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,150);
```

You can see into the ToneGenerator object (CMD + click over ToneGenerator. , in Mac), and choose another beep type besides `TONE_CDMA_PIP`, `150` is the duration in milliseconds, and `100` the volume.

Comment: How do we achieve a double beep with it?

Comment: @Mauker you can use 'ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP2' to achieve a double beep.

Comment: I ended up trying just that, and it works. Thanks for the comment Manoj!

Comment: @ManojPedvi HOW TO PLAY LONG BEEP ?

Comment: Heads up - You will need to adjust the `duration` argument (something like 300ms is good) to play `ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP2` or any longer beep

Comment: Make sure to call release() on toneGen instance when you are done using it to avoid creating resources overhead

Answer (score 26):

just adding josh's answer. you need to release `ToneGenerator` using `Handler`. especially if you got error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Init failed at android.media.ToneGenerator.native_setup(Native Method)` like i did.

the complete code :

```
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.ToneGenerator
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper

class BeepHelper
{
val toneG = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)

fun beep(duration: Int)
{
    toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_S, duration)
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.postDelayed({
        toneG.release()
    }, (duration + 50).toLong())
}
}
```

Comment: Bless you for including the import statements! If I'm trying to figure out how to do something, chances are I don't know where to find it, either. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 13):

For Kotlin:

```
ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100).startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP, 200)
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the Tone Generator was not loud enough for some reason.

I ended up using the Media Player and created a Beeper class allowing to play a beep sound with a specified volume.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import com.nfci.mesea.time.R
import kotlin.math.ln

class Beeper(val context: Context) {

    private val maxVolume = 100f
    private val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

    init {

        val beep = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.packageName + "/" + R.raw.beep)

        val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
            .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build()

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, beep)
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)

        mediaPlayer.prepare()
    }

    fun play(volume: Int){
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            val calculatedVolume = 1 - (ln(maxVolume - volume.toFloat()) / ln(maxVolume))
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(calculatedVolume, calculatedVolume)
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to create a media player during initialization, then you will not need to use URI.parse(), not need to call setDataSource() and prepare(), but only set attributes: `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep).apply{ setAudioAttributes(/*audioAttributes*/) }`