# Playing sounds by directly streaming to the audio device's driver in C#

Tags: c#, audio

my problem is, I want to play sounds whose frequency (Hz) is not an int, meaning I can't use Console.Beep(),
but I don't want to play sounds out of a file so I also can't use System.Media.SoundPlayer(),
is there any way I can stream a Byte[] of the audio to the driver?
something that would kinda look like this

```
var device = /* audio device object*/
Byte[] sound = /*audio*/ 
var stream = device.OutputStream;
stream.Write(sound,0,sound.Length);
stream.Dispose();
```

Comment: You could use a library like NAudio. See for example this SO question: [How can I play byte array of audio raw data using NAudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792548/how-can-i-play-byte-array-of-audio-raw-data-using-naudio)

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509010/how-to-play-a-short-beep-to-android-phones-loudspeaker-programmatically/29509305